# Counterexample for finite dimensional weak convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, weak-convergence

Could you give an explicit construction of a sequence $\mathbb P_n$ of probability measures on $C[0,\infty]$ which converges in the sense of finite dimensional distributions BUT
does not converge weakly?

Also why is the converse always true how to show it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x_n\in C[0,\infty)$ piecewise linear, with $x_n(n^{-1})=1$, $x_n(0)=0$, $x_n(t)=0$ for $t\geqslant 2n^{-1}$. Take $\mu_n:=\delta_{x_n}$. The finite-dimensional distributions converge weakly to those of $\delta_{\mathbf 0}$.

Indeed, let $t_1,\dots,t_d\in (0,+\infty)$. Then $\mu_n\pi_{t_1,\dots,t_d}^{—1}=\delta_0$ when $n$ is large enough. Gluing $0$ to $t_1,\dots,t_d$ is not a problem.

But these is not weak convergence (because $(x_n,n\geqslant 1)$ doesn't converge uniformly to $0$). Indeed, one can show that if $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $(x_n,n\geqslant 1)$ is a sequence in $X$ and $x\in X$, then $\delta_{x_n}\to \delta_x$ in distribution if and only if $d(x_n,x)\to 0$.

However, for general $\mu_n$ and $\mu$, if $\mu_n\to \mu$ weakly, since the finite-dimensional projection are continuous, we have $\mu_n\pi^{-1}_{t_1,\dots,t_d}\to \mu\pi^{-1}_{t_1,\dots,t_d}$ for all integer $d$ and $t_1,\dots,t_d\in [0,\infty)$.

What was missing in the first example is *tightness*.

Comment: Davide thanks for the answer. Could you clarify a little bit your counterexample? Why are finite-dim. distributions converge weakly to  δ_0  I can not see it How to write it mathematically and see it? Also you said "no uniform convergence hence no weak convergence" can you give more details what theorem is that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SalihUcan See edit.